# NPM package: Can't resolve module entry point from package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I've recently created and published my first NPM package. I'm familiar with managing Nuget packages, but I'm new to managing NPM packages.

My problem is that when I try to consume my package and import it, I get a compiler warning for "Could not find symbol 'myClass' in external module 'myClass.provider.ts'.

I've read the npm package.json documentation, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My package.json has the following values for name and main:

`"name": "myCompany.package", 
"main": "src/myClass.js",`

and my import looks like: 

`import { myClass } from "myCompany.package";`

Inside my package, after installing it, the entry file is correctly located at `src/myClass.Js`. What am I missing?

Comment: In `src/myClass.js`, what does the `module.exports=...` or `exports.xxx=...` or `export default ...` look like?

Comment: I have `exports.myClass = myClass;` in my `src/myClass.js`